# Pinescript- How do I return a single value from an array?

Tags: arrays, pine-script, pine-script-v5

I tried `array.get(arrayName, 0)` - isn't this supposed to return the 0th element of the array? Instead it returns a series float?

Answer (score 0):

I've just realised- I actually do need to compare 2 series values.

Comparing 2 series values actually only compares 2 individual values at any specific point. (This seems obvious now.)